# Add new binding to a Guice Module?

Tags: java, spring, module, guice, inject

I've my own Guice module and in the configure method, I've provided my own bindings as under -

```
public void configure() {
    MapBinder<String, ExternalDatabaseConnection> m = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, ExternalDatabaseConnection.class);
    m.addBinding("DBServer1").to(ExternalDBServer1Connection.class);
    m.addBinding("DBServer2").to(ExternalDBServer2Connection.class);
}
```

The above is deployed as a web application.
I want to let third party providers be able to provide there own implementations and give a jar file for connection class. How do I do that? That is instead of modifying code above to add new binding like below -

```
m.addBinding("DBServer3").to(ExternalDBServer3Connection.class);
```

Comment: Third party code is already able to do this, simply by installing your module and then using `MapBinder` themselves.

Answer (score 4):

You may combine modules. Here is an example. Let's say you have extenral and internal modules that live separately.

```
public class InternalModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        MapBinder<String, String> m = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, String.class);
        m.addBinding("DBServer1").toInstance("Value1");
        m.addBinding("DBServer2").toInstance("Value2");
    }

}
```

and:

```
public class ExternalModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        MapBinder<String, String> m = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, String.class);
        m.addBinding("DBServer3").toInstance("Value3");
    }

}
```

Here is an injector based on the combination of the two modules (e.g. this may live in your app and you may implement some simple registration mechanism):

```
InternalModule moduleInt = new InternalModule();
ExternalModule moduleExt = new ExternalModule();

Module combined = Modules.combine(moduleInt, moduleExt);

Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(combined);
```

When this injector injects a map, e.g.:

```
@Inject
private Map<String, String> stringMap;
```

this map will contain the following values:

```
{DBServer1=Value1, DBServer2=Value2, DBServer3=Value3}
```

[Javadoc of Modules](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/util/Modules.html).

It is also possible to override modules instead of combining them. In this case external libraries will replace your own implementations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Contributing mapbindings from different modules is supported.

Check [this](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) for more details.